# Add easily readable scale bar to ggmap (using ggsn package?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am working on inserting a scale bar into some of my maps. I work with ggmaps and am currently using the ggsn package to insert a scale bar. However, this scale bar is extremely difficult to read on the types of maps I'm working with (see map below). I would like to either (a) find a way to make it easier to read, (b) have the scale bar be outside the map boundaries, or (c) use a different package that allows for easier customization.

Essentially, my code looks something like this. This example should be easily reproducible.

```
map <- get_map(location = c(146, 15), zoom = 8,
               maptype = “satellite”, source = "google") 

Map <- ggmap(map)

Map + ggsn::scalebar(x.min = 144.5, x.max = 147.5,
           y.min = 13.5, y.max = 16.5, 
           dist = 50, dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84')
```

And produces a map like the one below, where the scale bar in the bottom right corner is hard to read.

[image: ggmap with scalebar]

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: `ggsn::scalebar` does not look very configurable, without rewriting the function. Depending on what kind of output you want, the `leaflet` package may be an option (it is for interactive HTML/JS maps, but can generate static maps too). Happy to post a leaflet solution if it sounds useful.

Comment: Does leaflet work with ggplot2? A significant portion of my script depends on being able to plot stuff on top of the map with ggplot2. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, leaflet is quite separate to ggplot2. I can only suggest looking at the code for the scalebar function to see whether it can be modified.

Comment: Added an answer showing how to modify the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development version of `scalebar` at Github has new arguments, `st.color` and `box.fill`, which allow better customisation of the bar.

Install that version using:

```
devtools::install_github('oswaldosantos/ggsn')
```

And then use *e.g.*:

```
ggmap(Map) + 
  my_scalebar(x.min = 144.5, x.max = 147.5,
            y.min = 13.5,  y.max = 16.5,
            dist = 50, dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84',
            box.fill = c("yellow", "white), st.color = "white")
```

[image]

**OLDER ANSWER**

*I wrote this answer on how to modify the function before discovering the newer version.*

I think the best approach here is to modify the `scalebar` function.

First, you need to load the `ggsn` package and edit the function:

```
library(ggsn)
my_scalebar <- edit(scalebar)
```

This should pop up an editor.  Modify the top of the function so that it looks like this:

```
function (data = NULL, location = "bottomright", dist, height = 0.02, 
  st.dist = 0.02, st.bottom = TRUE, st.size = 5, dd2km = NULL, 
  model, x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max, anchor = NULL, facet.var = NULL, 
  facet.lev = NULL, box2_fill = "yellow", legend_color = "white")
{
  require(maptools)
```

We added 3 things:

- an argument `box2_fill` with default value = "yellow"
- an argument `legend_color` with default value = "white"
- require `maptools` because the function uses `gcDestination()` from that package

Next, look for the line that begins `gg.box2` and alter it to use the value for `box2_fill`:

```
  gg.box2 <- geom_polygon(data = box2, aes(x, y), fill = box2_fill, 
    color = "black")
```

Then, edit the section near the bottom of the function to use the value for `legend_color`:

```
else {
    gg.legend <- annotate("text", label = paste0(legend[, 
      "text"], "km"), x = x.st.pos, y = st.dist, size = st.size,
      color = legend_color)
  }
```

Saving will close the editor and save the new function `my_scalebar` to your work space.

Now you can use the new function. You can either supply values to the new arguments `box2_fill =` and `legend_color =`, or just try the defaults:

```
ggmap(Map) + 
  my_scalebar(x.min = 144.5, x.max = 147.5,
            y.min = 13.5,  y.max = 16.5,
            dist = 50, dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84')
```

And if you think your edits are useful, you could suggest them to the package developer using a pull request [at Github](https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn). NOTE: it looks like the developer has started to address this issue, since the Github version of `scalebar` has new `box.fill` and `st.color` arguments.

Comment: one edit to this answer: dd2km is depreciated. It needs to be replaced with transform = TRUE, dist_unit = "km"